# How can I optimize my search?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq

I'm just writing a test application to work out how I can optimise searching on a large number of records, to be displayed in a gridview.

For the time being, I have a test table with 20,000 records (non-indexed at the moment) and I'm looking to display the records in batches of 20 in my gridview. I'm not really sure how to do this though and I'm trying to understand the theory behind it.

```
namespace TestingIndexes
{
  public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      gvResults.DataSource = GetContacts();
      gvResults.DataBind();
    }

    private List<Contact> GetContacts()
    {
      List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();

      DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

      // Track time elapsed
      Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();

      var result = from c in dc.GetTable<Contact>()
      select c;

      sw.Stop();
      ltMessage.Text = "<p>Time elapsed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "</p>";

      if (result.Count() > 0)
        contacts = result.ToList<Contact>();

      return contacts;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is a very simple query using LINQ and I'm pretty sure I don't want to be bringing 20,000 records into memory every time in order to bind it to the gridview. What is the alternative though? I suppose what I'm looking to do is ultimately query the database to find out many records there are, but then only show 20 records at a time in the gridview. Is this something that is handled by SQL Server? I'm sure there must be articles on what I'm trying to do but I'm not entirely sure what I should be searching for. Any pointers or links to tutorials would be very helpful!

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: As a side note using the code in you question will actually query the database twice for all the data, once for the `Count()` operation and once for the `ToList()` operation. My rule is never (if it can be avoided) use the extension method `Count()`

Comment: So how would you check there have been records returned without using .Count()?

Comment: Just do ToList() (evaluated the query), and than count on the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Skip` and `Take` to get parts of data from a database table.

```
var result = dc.GetTable<Contact>().Skip(40).Take(20).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - that clears up how to retrieve the required records. However I'm confused about where to store the 'bulk' of the data. For example, do I query the database and pull out ALL the records into memory, and then use the skip/take on this? Or is there a more efficient way of doing this? Excuse my poor wording but is it possible to pull out all the records and store them in a temp result table in sql server, and then use the skip/take on this result set?

Comment: No, to query in my answer will be translated into SQL that will only retrieve the specified rows

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. Surely the records need to be stored in a temporary table for you to page through? Otherwise records could be added to the database while you're paging that'll distort the results...

Comment: Sure rows can be added to the table while you are paging, but I dot see that as a problem.

Comment: Ah ok well thanks - it at least gives me something to investigate further :-)

Comment: If you want to make sure that only rows that were available during the initial query are coming you can add a timestamp column to the table and only retrieve rows that have a dateTime less than when you made the initial query.

Answer (score 0):

First, last and allways build a (clustered) index on the table Ideally an index covering the rows you want to return as well. If you dont then SQL will step through ALL the records. If the covering index is in place SQL will only access the index. if you want to learn about SQL then there is probably no better source than http://www.sqlserverinternals.com/ Kalen Delaney. "Covering indexes" and much much more are all explained with clarity and even a superficial understand of what is in her book will make you a much better developer oh and there is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index